# How to get element from component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I Have some script, that takes element, but i cant find how to get it from react component. At least, i can get element after rendering, but now i have another problem - cant make event on button, coz i need SignatureObj

```
var SignaturePad = require('signature_pad');

var SignatureWidget = React.createClass({

    _handleClear: function(e, SignatureObj) {
        SignatureObj.clear();
    },

    _getSignature: function(canvas) {
        return new SignaturePad(canvas);
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {

        var wrapper = this.getDOMNode(),
            canvas  = wrapper.querySelector('canvas'),
            SignatureObj = this._getSignature(canvas);
    },

    render: function() {
        var canvas = React.createElement('canvas');

        return (
            <div>
                {canvas}
                <button>Clear</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Finally, i need to get something like this

```
render: function() {
    var canvas = React.createElement('canvas'),
        >> canvasEl = canvas.getElement(),<< magic
        SignatureObj = this._getSignature(canvasEl);

    return (
        <div>
            {canvas}
            <button onClick={this._handleClear.bind(this, SignatureObj)}>Clear</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first some side notes, getDOMNode is deprecated, u should use findDOMNode, further u don't need to use create element within the render, because if you use the jsx syntax which u do it will be converted to the syntax u are using (createlement ..etc .. under the hood)

for your problem about selecting the element:

```
    React.findDOMNode(this.refs.findMe)
```

<-- makes u find the node or as u call it :D (Magic)

```
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <canvas ref='findMe'></canvas> <------- magic
                <button>Clear</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Hope this helps!
some good reads:

refs:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html

jsx:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

Answer (score 0):

i used this way to add event

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    var pad             = this.refs.pad.getDOMNode(),
        saveButton      = this.refs.save.getDOMNode(),
        clearButton     = this.refs.clear.getDOMNode(),
        SignatureObj    = this._getSignature(pad);

    clearButton.onclick = this._handleClear.bind(this, SignatureObj);
    saveButton.onclick  = this._handleSave.bind(this, SignatureObj);
},
```

Comment: U shouldn't do it like that, react has its own way of handling onclick events, u are bypassing it. they way it did it before within the render is the way to do it (with onClick)

The reason the binding would not work in your example before is becouse u didnt have the canvas El, and SignatureObj would be undefined, but

  <button onClick={this._handleClear.bind(this, SignatureObj)}>Clear</button>

 Is the way to do it

Comment: facebook on events: 
"facebook: With React you simply pass your event handler as a camelCased prop similar to how you'd do it in normal HTML. React ensures that all events behave identically in IE8 and above by implementing a synthetic event system. That is, React knows how to bubble and capture events according to the spec, and the events passed to your event handler are guaranteed to be consistent with the W3C spec, regardless of which browser you're using.

Comment: and as said in my answer, u should not use getDOMNode.

facebook: 
getDOMNode is deprecated and has been replaced with React.findDOMNode().
This method is not available on ES6 class components that extend React.Component. It may be removed entirely in a future version of React.